# MicrositeURL() to access parent BU microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, microsites

I have a parent and a child business unit, the parent BU is not the top-level BU but also a child of the top-level. Like this:

```
Top-level BU
|__ Child BU A
    |__ Child BU B
```

The microsite lives in `Child BU A`, and the email is being sent from `Child BU B`. Using `MicrositeURL()` I am getting the error **The page you have requested is unavailable!**.

The documentation here states that child BU's can access microsites from the top-level BU but does not specify if any other parent BUs can be used. https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/sites/MicrositeURL.html

Does anyone know if this is possible? Because of client data restrictions we cannot have the microsite living at the top-level.

Comment: What happens when you hardcode the URL for the microsite page?

Comment: This won't work because the microsite relies on email send data being passed through the encrypted URL. It is being used as a preference center.

Comment: Wouldn't the link wrapping include that data?

Comment: Sorry can you post a code snippet of what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind.  I think you may just have to include the parameters manually since the encrypted parameters will be business unit specific.  I've had to do that on preference centers that can be visited from emails *and* externals sources.